# Linked list C char set last name added to everyone

Tags: c, linked-list, char

I wrote a program to be used as a line organizer, but when the time comes to show the a person's name, it sets the last person added to all others.  How can I fix it?
If I change the info in `struct`, it bugs; however, if someone can help me, I'd be glad.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int priority;
  int info;
  struct node *link;
} *front = NULL;

void insert(char person[20], int person_priority);
int del();
void display();
int isEmpty();

int main() //!! fixed
{
  int choice, person_priority;
  char person[20];

  while (1) {
    printf("1.Insert Person\n");
    printf("2.Attend Client\n");
    printf("3.Show Queue\n");
    printf("4.Exit\n");
    printf("Type choice : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      printf("Type persons name:");
      scanf("%s", &person);
      printf("Its Priority:\n1 Pregnant\n2 Older\n3 Standard: ");
      scanf("%d", &person_priority);
      insert(person, person_priority);
      system("cls");
      break;
    case 2:
      system("cls");
      printf("Person was attended", del());
      break;
    case 3:
      system("cls");
      display();
      break;
    case 4:
      exit(1);
    default:
      printf("Invalid Choice\n");
    }                           /*end of switch */
  }                             /*end of while */
  return 0;   //!! fixed
}                               /*end of main() */


void insert(char person[20], int person_priority)
{
  struct node *tmp, *p;

  tmp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("No Memory available\n");
    return;
  }

  tmp->info = person;
  tmp->priority = person_priority;
/*Starting list*/
  if (isEmpty() || person_priority < front->priority) {
    tmp->link = front;
    front = tmp;
  }
  else {
    p = front;
    while (p->link != NULL && p->link->priority <= person_priority)
      p = p->link;
    tmp->link = p->link;
    p->link = tmp;
  }
}                               /*end of insere() */

int del()
{
  struct node *tmp;
  int person;

  if (isEmpty()) {
    printf("Empty Queue\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    tmp = front;
    person = tmp->info;
    front = front->link;
    free(tmp);
  }

  return person;
}                               /*end of del() */

int isEmpty()
{
  if (front == NULL)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}                               /*end of emtpy verification (isEmpty()) */

void display()
{
  struct node *ptr;
  ptr = front;
  if (isEmpty())
    printf("Empty Queu\n");
  else {
    printf("Line :\n");
    printf("Priority       Name\n");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
      printf("%5d        %5s\n", ptr->priority, ptr->info);
      ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: First, `tmp->info = person;`, is **wrong**, `tmp->info` is an `int`. Second, you're reading all names into the same array, and let `tmp->info` "point" to that (if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(char*)`, it will horribly break in addition to being wrong). You need to copy the names to some persistent memory.

Comment: So what must I put on "tmp->info = person"? Any idea how to copy the names? Im new at this... Thank you.

Comment: Make `info` a `char*` if you use it as one, and then take a look at `strlen`, `malloc`, and `strcpy` for copying the names.

Comment: I changed the info to "char info[20]", but now the compiler tells "incompatible assingments". And how to use the strcpy? Could you type it as a line to I insert on the code?
Plase help me!!
tahnks

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. `strcpy(tmp->info, person)`, but reading the man page would give you the answer faster.

Comment: I didnt get yet, now it doesnt let me input any name, it does jump direct to "its priority".
What must I change now?
pleaseee

Comment: Apparently you have a newline in the input buffer from a previous `scanf` (or some other whitespace). Make it `scanf(" %s", &person);` to skip initial whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct node has an element named "info" which is of type int. Every time you add a person, you use scanf() to read the person's name into a character array, and you then pass the address of that character array to insert() which stores the address in the integer "info". Every `struct node` that you allocate, you're storing the same address of the same variable in it. Every time you scanf(), you're overwriting the same memory.

Your struct node should have an element `char info[20]` and when you create a new node, you should `strcpy()` the person's name into tmp->info.

Also note that the way you're treating a variable alternately as type char* and as type int leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: And how to do it? Could you please code this part? I really want to learn but i cant understand everything.